# PHP CURL GET JSON VALUE

Tags: php, curl

Hi I have used curl to get some json api data and that is all working fine. I have ran into a problem when trying to get a specific value. I have decoded the json into an array but I still cant seem to get a specific value.

Here is my code:

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getcurrencies');

$result = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);

$json = json_decode($result, true);

print_r($json);
```

so if you go to this url https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getcurrencies you can see the data I am pulling in. I want to get the value of a Currency.

I tried changing my print to this `print_r($json['Currency']);` that returned nothing. I also tried this `print_r($json[1]);` which I thought would at least return something but yet again I got no response.

I have run `print_r(gettype($json));` that returned an array so it is 100% an array.

Comment: it's in 'result', as you see in the data you've linked to. `$json['result'][0]['Currency']`

Comment: @Jeff what do I do to get the cointype of something by using the Currency name

Comment: just loop through that array to find it or use one of the [native array functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php)

Answer (score 0):

The result of that call is indeed an array, but it's not structured that way. To get the currency of the first result, you'll have to do `print_r($json['result'][0]['Currency'])`, `print_r($json['result'][1]['Currency'])` for the second result, and so on.

EDIT: Jeff beat me to it.